# Is there a way to hide the image before it appears at certain coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is a pull to refresh `Image` parameters:

```
 Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
      .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy))
      .foregroundColor(.gray)
      .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: refresh.started ? 180 : 0))
      .offset(y: -25)
      .animation(.easeIn)
```

```
@State var refresh = Refresh(started: false, released: false)
VStack {
...               // layer that u can see on the screen with arrow under it

}
                .zIndex(1)
                .background(
                    ZStack {
                        let color = scheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white
                        LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [color, color, color, color, color, color, color.opacity(0.6)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    }
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                )

// and here start pull to refresh with scrollview

                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true,
                           content: {
                    GeometryReader { reader -> AnyView in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if refresh.startOffset == 0 {
                                refresh.startOffset = reader.frame(in: .global).minY
                            }
                            refresh.offset = reader.frame(in: .global).minY
                            
                            if refresh.offset - refresh.startOffset > 80 && !refresh.started {
                                refresh.started = true
                            }
                            if refresh.startOffset == refresh.offset && refresh.started && !refresh.released {
                                
                                withAnimation(Animation.linear){refresh.released = true}
                                updateData()
                            }
                            if refresh.startOffset == refresh.offset && refresh.started && !refresh.released && refresh.invalid {
                                
                                refresh.invalid = false
                                updateData()
                            }
                        }
                        
                        return AnyView(Color.black.frame(width: 0, height: 0))
                    }


struct Refresh {
    var startOffset : CGFloat = 0
    var offset : CGFloat = 0
    var started : Bool
    var released : Bool
    var invalid : Bool = false
    
}
```

The arrow at rest is under another layer that has an `opacity` property:

[image]

When I drag the `ScrollView` to refresh the arrow goes out from under the layer:

[image]

The question is very simple, what parameters should be applied to hide the arrow at rest?

Comment: not enough code, can you send the rest of the screen?

Comment: @GrandSirr do you need all the code that is related to refresh or do you need a screenshot of current `View` with `ScrollView`?

Comment: Show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
that is simple but replicates your issue, then we can try to find a solution.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I thought the refresh structure was not important, I assumed that there are ways to somehow hide the image itself at certain coordinates. But I added what is needed.

Comment: @GrandSirr I added the necessary block of code, what do you say? thanks.